# Determine uncertainty of regression prediction with logged explanatory and response variables

Tags: regression, uncertainty, statsmodels

I'm creating a univariate regression where the explanatory and response variables have a non-linear relationship.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.array([314.4, 960.5667, 357.0667, 507.2, 811.6667, 476.2333, 681.7667, 723.8666, 943.8333, 388.7, 730.2667, 126.7, 173.709, 354.0667, 596.4667, 822.7667, 591.8167, 916.9667, 707.2, 499.6333])

y = np.array([353.483,778.207,368.587,576.420,923.510,537.603,582.840,742.587,834.363,444.093,576.053,129.473,232.280,374.032,560.028,830.977,618.778,844.560,757.705,494.980])

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The logs of x and y display a linear relationship. I want to run a regression and also obtain uncertainty measurements for the predictions.  We know that at the lower range of the x variable, as shown above, the uncertainty of the regression will be lower in absolute terms than at higher ranges.

I thought I can use the standard error of the regression coefficient to represent this uncertainty, but it is very low (0.0015921), and will give me 1 if I exponentiate it.  Note that in addition to taking the log, I perform some manipulation of the data to fit in with my use-case.

```
x_transf = np.log(x * 6500)
y_transf = np.log(y * 1000) 

model = sm.OLS(y_transf, x_transf).fit()
coef = model.params[0]

model.bse
```

Is there a more appropriate method for quantifying the uncertainty of the predictions so that its lower in absolute terms for the lower range of x?

Comment: aside: did you intentionally leave out the constant in the regression? add_constant?

Comment: Yes, it is intentional, there is no intercept in the real world this model represents.

Comment: standard errors for nonlinear prediction will need delta method. confidence intervals for simple functions (in one parameter) can be obtained by endpoint transformation. But I don't have a quick recipe using statsmodels https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2791#issuecomment-1307453181 to keep track of this.